# удаление строки с ListBox

Tags: c#

Помогите удалить текст  записанный в Textbox из Listbox нажатием кнопки

```
    private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox1.Text != "")
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);

    }

    private void radioButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("выберите элемент");
    }
```

Comment: listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);

Comment: `listBox.Items.Remove(textBox.Text)`